# Python project not importing a local module

Tags: python, flask, apache2

I have a python project using Flask and I have a form I have setup in a module I called forms. I test my app in Windows and it works just fine. I then update my project on Debian where I use Apache2 to run the project. There I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forms'`

My project is organized like so:

```
flaskapp.wsgi
flask_app
    __init__.py
    forms.py
```

And `__init__.py` starts with:

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template, send_from_directory, abort
from requests import Request, Session
from forms import OrderForm
```

I checked the `sys.path` with:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

when using the python console and got:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to get it to use `forms` as a module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `from .forms import OrderForm`.
This is referencing to the same folder. Otherwise flask_app.forms should work too.

Comment: I thought I tried that already. Regardless, I don't get that error anymore now. Thank you!

Comment: No worries,  I know situations, where one try out everything, but in the end oversee the correct solution. Happy I could help.

Comment: The weird thing about this is now it doesn't work in Windows saying `__main__` is not a package.

Comment: Hmm, that has to be something else. I have to work with windows at work and this should work .